# What is 'address' in the following Java code? Is it a separate Java class or a user defined data type?

Tags: java

Please explain the "  Address address; " in the following Java code snippet.

```
class Employee{  
    Address address;  
    Employee(){  
    address=new Address();  
    }  

}
```

Comment: It is the declaration of an instance member `address` of type `Address`. This is extremely basic.

Comment: Just an assumption, but it probably means the physical address of the employee in question. And yes, it is almost certainly an instance of a user-degined class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more context, I would guess it is a user defined class.

If you could show us the imports at the top of the class we'd be able to to answer more accurately.